# Area of the intersection of two circles

Tags: geometry

[image]

The area of a square is $a^2$. Two quarter circles intersect in the square and form a symmetry along the square’s diameter. Where have I failed in the process of finding the area of the intersection?

1. Find area of circle (take $\frac 14$ part of it): $A=\frac 14 \pi a^2$
2. Find area of square: $B=a^2$
3. How much bigger is the square than the quarter circle? $B-A=C$
4. Answer is $A-C=\frac 14 \pi a^2-a^2-\frac 14 \pi a^2$

Thank you!

Comment: Note that the overlapping quarter circles cover that intersection *twice*.

Comment: The answer should be $B - 2C = 2A - B = (\frac\pi2-1)a^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong in step 4 because:
$$
A-C=A-(B-A)=A-B+A=2A-B
$$
not
$$
A-C=A-B-A
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You have successfully found the area of the quarter circle to be $$\frac 14 \pi a^2$$

We can say that the area we are trying to find is called $A$ and we can also see that the two quarter circles cover the whole area of the square and overlap in the area $A$. Therefore \begin{align}2\times \text{quarter circle area} &= \text{sqaure area} + \text{desired area}\\
2\times \left(\frac14 \pi a^2\right)&=a^2+A\\
A&=2\times \left(\frac14 \pi a^2\right)-a^2\\
&=\frac12 \pi a^2-a^2\\
&=a^2\left(\frac \pi2-1\right)\\
&\approx 0.571a^2\end{align}

That is to say that the desired area is around $57\%$ the size of the square

Comment: Thanks for editing my question so beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Using your notations, you computed the area of one "missing corner" $B-A$.

What you are looking for is the area of the square minus the two missing corners:

$$B-2(B-A) = 2A -B. $$

I leave the rest of the calculations up to you.